# Force python to NEVER flush File to disk

Tags: python, io

I have a scenario where I read file content from url using `request`.

```
    f = open(..., 'wb')
    for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
        f.write(chunk)
```

However I do not want to actually write the file to disk as I want to continue manipulating the content of `f` that I downloaded.

Is there a way to tell `f` to never write to disk?

Comment: Have you considered not writing it to disk?

Comment: Why are you involving a file at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) or [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) instead of real file object, because they works like file except they write content in memory instead of file.

```
f = io.BytesIO()   # Use `io.StringIO` if you want text mode (not binary mode)
for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
    f.write(chunk)
```

---

BTW, instead of looping + `write`, you can use [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines):

> `writelines(lines)` Write a list of lines to the stream. Line separators
>   are not added, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a
>   line separator at the end.

```
f.writelines(message_content.iter_content())
```

Comment: I was going to say that, but I was 15 seconds late. :-)

Comment: Considering that the questioner doesn't want the "disk" part of file functionality, it's not clear that they really need any other part of the functionality of a file-like object. All they say in the question is that they want to "continue manipulating the content". Assuming this `message_content` thing is a `requests.Response` object, they might be better served by `message_content.content` to get a bytestring representing the message content, or just working with `message_content.iter_content()` directly.

Comment: @user2357112, Yup. If OP want whole content at once, `content` should be used. But OP mentioned `manipulating`.. so I suggested `io.BytesIO`,`io.StringIO`. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @user2357112 got a point. I will look into that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply collect all chunks in a binary object. No need to involve files.

```
result = b''
for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
    result += chunk
```

Or:

```
result = b''.join(message_content.iter_content())
```